# Choosing a development stack for web based data vis/mining

Tags: python, r, jvm, programming-languages, data-munging

I would like to know what various folks in the community think about tool/language choices for a small team (3-5) developers working build simple data driven applications. We want to do data munging/Analysis/Datavis.

We will likely ultimately have Hadoop on the data crunching end and will have javascript on the front end. Ideally we want some level of R integration too.

My best thought at the moment is Django, Python, using R with Rpy (http://rpy.sourceforge.net/) and Boto (http://code.google.com/p/boto/).

Are there other good alternatives? Would there be any significant down/up sides to trying to go a JVM route instead? What tools would you use and why?

Comment: have you considered pylons/pyramid? It makes fewer assumptions about the back-end (among other things). I am using pylons for a data warehouse project and will consider transitioning soon to pyramid.

Comment: Hi! For Data mining and analysis the main language is in very many cases R. So in my eyes the focus should be on the main language to do the data analysis and to do it very good. What stack is involved to present that data is a less critical I guess. Javascript can access Rest Interfaces (http middlewhere) via ajax, so most things work. I would use R, Haskell, Javascript, because they have advanced features but have a steep learning curve. R is not good for natural language stuff. I would use Hadoop only for 5 terabyte plus or for very time critical stuff (GBs in miliseconds).

Comment: maybe you could hit what kind of analysis you want to to, data you, what your data is ("time series", or "text", "business data", etc") and how large you expect your data to be (about 100GB, or much above or below)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of JVM you could check [rApache](http://rapache.net/) and [rserve](http://www.rforge.net/Rserve/) also. Well, I have no idea though what extra would you get instead of using Rpy.

Comment: do you happen to know a simple r-package that implements http PUT and DELETE, so a restful service can be written? In Addition to rApache and rserve the package "R.rsp" is nice.

Comment: @mrsteve: thanks for pointing my attention to *R.rsp*, I will check this library. About http PUT adn DELETE: I am not sure but would think that *RCurl* would work.